# Responsive NAV IE

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar that works very well in Chrome - however it fails in Internet explorer 8 or less.

the link is [www.notebox.ca/AP](http://www.notebox.ca/AP) - you may view the code there.

I know there is bootstrap, but I was wondering if there is any way to add something to the code to make it work in IE.

Thanks

Comment: "Internet explorer 8 or less"

Comment: Media queries are only [supported in IE9 or above](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries). You'll need to use a JavaScript polyfill

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond will polyfill the missing functionality you need in older IEs.